# How to foreach in store method in laravel?

Tags: laravel, loops, foreach, store

I have the following array in `dd($request->all())`

```
"question_id" => array:2 [▼
    0 => "1"
    1 => "2"
  ]
  "answers" => array:2 [▼
    0 => "1 year"
    1 => "yes"
  ]
```

I need to loop this array to store in [this table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RwV2N.png)

which is this request came from dynamic form i create.
I've tried this method

```
$data = $request->all();
        $questions = $data['question_id'];
        $answers = $data['answers'];
        $dataanswer = [];
        foreach($answers as $answer){
            $dataanswer[] = [                
                'question_id'   => $questions,
                'answer'        => $answers
            ];            
      }
         Answers::insert($dataanswer);
```

but it says `Array to string conversion`, please help me.

Comment: Because in `$questions` and `$answers` you have arrays, so, `'question_id'   => $questions,` will make an attempt to insert an array into the question_id column

Comment: @porloscerrosΨ thanks for the answer, how do i take the value from requested array? so i can put into table

Comment: It depends on the structure of the table in DB. The @sta answer is good, you don't need a loop, I think that is what I would answer for how the question is posed. Edit the question by adding more information if that answer does not serve you for any reason

Answer (score 1):

You can use PHP's [`array_combine()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-combine.php) function :

```
$data = $request->all();
        $questions = $data['question_id'];
        $answers = $data['answers'];

Answers::insert(array_combine($questions, $answers));
```

Here is a [`demo`](https://rextester.com/SNXN20575)

Comment: thanks for the answer, looks like I asked the question wrong, what I need is how to retrieve the value from the array above, so that I can loop it to be inserted into the table.

Answer (score 1):

If your questions and answers in right order (e.g. 1 => '1 year' and 2 => 'yes), than:

```
$data = collect($request->input('question_id'))
    ->combine($request->input('answers'));

Model::insert($data);
```

Answer (score -1):

i end up using this method, and works perfectly

thanks for the answers guys stay healthy

```
$count = count($request->input('question_id'));
        for($i = 0 ;$i < $count ; $i++){
            $questions = $data['question_id'][$i];
            $answers = $data['answers'][$i];

            Answers::create([
                    'application_id'    => $applicant['id'],
                    'question_id'       => $questions,
                    'answer'            => $answers
                ]);
        }
```